# Finding max of value of Blancmange curve on closed interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h(x) = |x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend the definition of $h$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by requiring $h(x+2)=h(x)$. The result is a periodic "sawtooth" function. Let
$$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}h(2^n x). $$

> If possible, how do we find the/a value at which $g$ attains its maximum in the interval [0,2]? Furthermore, is the set of points where $g$ attains its maximum in the interval [0,2] finite/countable/uncountable?

I think we can rule out the rationals $\{1, \frac12, \frac14, \frac34, 
\frac18, \frac38, \frac58, \frac78, \ldots \}$ since $h(2^n x)=0$ at these values for all $n$ greater than some $N$.
Apart from that, I'm not sure what I can say. I tried constructing a sequence of maximums, but the behavior seems erratic and I don't think it will lead anywhere? This is from the second edition of Abbott (section 5.4) btw.

[image]

Comment: maybe you find useful information here: [link] (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.1691.pdf)

Comment: You can approach it with a cantor-set-style construction. Note the flats on every 2nd graph above. The maximums occur inside those intervals. The intersection of all such flat intervals should be the set of maximums.

Answer (score 0):

I split my head over this, but eventually, I found the maximum by splitting the problem in two substeps:

1. Find a suitable bound for $g$, which I found to be $4/3$.
2. Find $y\in\mathbb{R}$ where $g(y)=4/3$. I found that $g(\frac{2}{3})=\frac{4}{3}$.

**Proof**: For (1), the strategy is to look at the $g_{2m-1}$, where $m\geq 1$, and to show that

$$\max (g_{2m-1})\leq \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{4^{i-1}}=1+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^{m-1}}$$

Consider $g_1=h_0+h_1$. Graphing $h_0+h_1$ should convince you that its maximum value is 1, so the base case holds. Next, we take our inductive hypothesis to be that

$$g_{2m-1}\leq \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{4^{i-1}}$$

and to show that it holds for $m+1$. Note that

$$g_{2(m+1)-1}=g_{2m+1}=g_{2m-1}+h_{2m}+h_{2m+1}$$

An argument similar to the one for h_0+h_1 should convince you that $h_{2m}+h_{2m+1} $is bounded by $1/2^{2m}=1/4^m$. To get you started, note that it's enough to look at the interval $[0, 1/2^{2m-1}]$ where $h_{2m}$ does one full oscillation. Once you're convinced of that, we can use that to conclude that

$$\max(g_{2m+1})\leq \max(g_{2m-1})+\max(h_{2m}+h_{2m+1})\leq \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{4^{i-1}}+\frac{1}{4^m}=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}\frac{1}{4^{i-1}},$$

which proves the claim. Now we can conclude that

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\max(g_{2m-1})\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{i-1}}=\frac{4}{3}$$

From here you can justify to yourself that this implies $g(x)\leq 4/3$. $\square$

**Proof** of (2): As a preliminary, we first need to show that

$$h\left(2^n\cdot\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{2}{3}$$

We make use of that fact that $h(x)=2/3$ in $[0, 2]$ only when $x=2/3$ or $x=4/3$, and the fact that $h(x+2)=h(x)$. For the base case, note that

$$h\left(2^0\frac{2}{3}\right)=h\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{2}{3}$$

since $h(x)=x$ on $[0, 1]$. For the inductive case, we assume that

$$h\left(2^n\cdot\frac{2}{3}\right)=2/3$$

Because of the periodic nature of $h$, this implies that either there is $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$2^n\cdot\frac{2}{3}+a=\frac{2}{3}$$

or there is $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$2^n\cdot\frac{2}{3}+b=\frac{4}{3}$$.

Without loss of generality, we assume it's the case with $a$. Then we multiply the equation on both sides by 2 and rearrange to get:

$$2^{n+1}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{3}-2a$$

Using the periodic nature of $h$, we know get

$$h\left(2^{n+1}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\right)=h\left(\frac{4}{3}-2a\right)=h\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)=\frac{2}{3}$$

Now we can use this result to show that $g(2/3)=4/3$:

$$g\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^m}h\left(2^m\cdot\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{2}{3}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^m}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2=\frac{4}{3}\square$$